# Python 3.4 Tkinter - lagging

Tags: python, tkinter, lag

I'm doing this project Pac-man game for my python class at school. Everything was going well but... Yesterday, while I was finishing up some final function my game started lagging so bad. The problem is in the main loop I suppose but I can't find a solution... Here is some code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import threading
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random

points = []
matrix = []
```

class Game:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.tk = Tk()
    self.tk.title("Pac-man")
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width = 800, height = 700, bg = 'black')
    self.Pac = Pacman(self.canvas, 'yellow')
    self.Blinky = Ghost(self.canvas, 'red')
    self.score = 0
    self.scoreid = Label(self.tk,
                    text = "SCORE: {0}".format(self.score), bg = 'yellow', fg = 'black')
    self.scoreid.pack()
    for wall in outerWall: 
        self.drawWall(wall[0], wall[1], wall[2], wall[3])
        self.drawWall(800 - wall[0], wall[1], 800 - wall[2], wall[3])

    for wall in WierdWalls: 
        self.drawWall(wall[0], wall[1], wall[2], wall[3])
        self.drawWall(800 - wall[0], wall[1], 800 - wall[2], wall[3])

    for wall in BaseOfGhost:
        self.drawWall(wall[0], wall[1], wall[2], wall[3])
        self.drawWall(800 - wall[0], wall[1], 800 - wall[2], wall[3])
    self.canvas.create_line(350, 270, 450, 270, width = 5, fill = 'yellow')

    for wall in squareWalls: 
        self.drawSquareWall(wall[0], wall[1], wall[2], wall[3])
        self.drawSquareWall(800 - wall[0], wall[1], 800 - wall[2], wall[3])

    self.drawPoints()
    self.Pac.draw()
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.tk.update
    self.running = True

def drawWall(self, x0, y0, x1, y1, width = 3, color = 'blue'):
    self.canvas.create_line(x0, y0, x1, y1, width = width, fill = color)

def drawSquareWall(self, x0, y0, x1, y1, width = 2, color = 'black'):
    self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill = color)
    self.canvas.create_line(x0, y0, x1, y0, width = width, fill = 'blue')
    self.canvas.create_line(x1, y0, x1, y1, width = width, fill = 'blue')
    self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x0, y1, width = width, fill = 'blue')
    self.canvas.create_line(x0, y1, x0, y0, width = width, fill = 'blue')

def drawPoints(self):
    self.BuildHorizontalPath(40, 40, 13, 26)
    self.BuildVerticalPath(40, 40, 9, 16)
    self.BuildHorizontalPath(66, 168, 4, 26)
    self.BuildHorizontalPath(66, 104, 4, 26)
    self.BuildVerticalPath(170, 56, 8, 16)
    self.BuildVerticalPath(170, 192, 18, 24)
    self.BuildHorizontalPath(196, 104, 8, 26)
    self.BuildVerticalPath(352, 56, 3, 16)
    self.BuildHorizontalPath(40, 456, 5, 26)
    self.BuildHorizontalPath(40, 600, 5, 26)
    self.BuildVerticalPath(40, 472, 4, 16)
    self.BuildHorizontalPath(66, 520, 2, 26)
    self.BuildVerticalPath(92, 536, 4, 16 )
    self.BuildVerticalPath(40, 600, 4, 18)
    self.BuildHorizontalPath(66, 654, 12, 27)
    self.BuildHorizontalPath(200, 527, 7, 27)
    self.BuildHorizontalPath(200, 456, 7, 27)
    self.BuildVerticalPath (362, 472, 3, 18)
    self.BuildVerticalPath (274, 135, 3, 20)
    self.BuildHorizontalPath (292, 175, 4, 18)
    self.BuildVerticalPath (254, 550, 3, 20)
    self.BuildHorizontalPath (274, 591, 5, 22)
    self.BuildVerticalPath (363, 611, 2, 20)

def BuildHorizontalPath(self, val1, val2, number, increment = 25, delta = 8):
    x, y = val1, val2
    itemid1 = 0
    itemid2 = 0
    for i in range(number):
        deltax = x + delta
        deltay = y + delta
        itemid1 = self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, deltax, deltay, fill = 'white')
        itemid2 = self.canvas.create_oval(800-x, y, 800-deltax, deltay, fill = 'white')
        points.append([(deltax + x)/2, (deltay + y)/2, itemid1])
        points.append([800-(deltax + x)/2, (deltay+y)/2, itemid2])
        x += increment

def BuildVerticalPath(self, val1, val2, number, increment = 30, delta = 8):
    itemid1 = 0
    itemid2 = 0
    for i in range(number):
        x, y = val1, val2
        deltax = x + delta
        deltay = y + delta
        itemid1 = self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, deltax, deltay, fill = 'white')
        itemid2 = self.canvas.create_oval(800-x, y, 800-deltax, deltay, 
            fill = 'white')
        points.append([(deltax + x)/2, (deltay + y)/2, itemid1])
        points.append([800-(deltax + x)/2, (deltay + y)/2, itemid2])
        val2 += increment

def mainloop(self):
    while 1:
        if self.running:
            first_moment = round(time.time())
            if not self.Pac.hitwall():
                self.Pac.canvas.move(self.Pac.id, self.Pac.x, self.Pac.y)
            if self.Pac.feed():
                self.score = self.score + 10
                self.scoreid.config(text = "SCORE: {0}".format(self.score))
            if self.Pac.first_teleport():
                self.Pac.canvas.move(self.Pac.id, 760, 0)

            if self.Pac.second_teleport():
                self.Pac.canvas.move(self.Pac.id, -760, 0)

            if not self.Blinky.hitwall():
                self.Blinky.canvas.move(self.Blinky.id, self.Blinky.x, self.Blinky.y)
            if self.Blinky.hitwall():
                self.Blinky.change_direction()

            last_moment = round(time.time())
            self.tk.update_idletasks()
            self.tk.update()
            s = 0.01 - (last_moment - first_moment)
            if s >= 0:
                time.sleep(s)
```

class Pacman:

```
def __init__(self, canvas, color):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 35, 35, fill = color)
    self.canvas.move(self.id, 400, 375)
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', self.go_up)
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Down>', self.go_down)
    self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease>', self.stop)
    #self.canvas.bind_all(self.hitwall, self.stop)

def feed(self):
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    for point in points:
        if  point[0] >= pos[0] and point[0] <= pos[2]:
            if point[1] >= pos[1] and point[1] <= pos[3]:
                self.canvas.delete(point[2])
                points.remove(point)
                return True
        if  point[1] >= pos[1] and point[1] <= pos[3]:
            if point[0] >= pos[0] and point[0] <= pos[2]:
                self.canvas.delete(point[2])
                points.remove(point)
                return True
    return False

def stop(self, event):
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0

def turn_left(self, event):
    self.x = -2

def turn_right(self, event):
    self.x = 2

def go_up(self, event):
    self.y = -2

def go_down(self, event):
    self.y = 2

def draw(self):
    self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)

def hitwall(self):
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    pos[0] += self.x
    pos[1] += self.y
    pos[2] += self.x
    pos[3] += self.y
    for wall in squareWalls:
        if pos[1] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
            if pos[0] in range(wall[0], wall[2]):
                return True
            if pos[2] in range(wall[0], wall[2]):
                return True
        elif pos[3] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
            if pos[0] in range(wall[0], wall[2]):
                return True
            if pos[2] in range(wall[0], wall[2]):
                return True
        if pos[1] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
            if pos[0] >= 800 - wall[2] and pos[0]<= 800 - wall[0]:
                return True
            if pos[2] >= 800 - wall[2] and pos[2]<= 800 - wall[0]:
                return True
        elif pos[3] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
            if pos[0] >= 800 - wall[2] and pos[0]<= 800 - wall[0]:
                return True
            if pos[2] >= 800 - wall[2] and pos[2]<= 800 - wall[0]:
                return True

    for wall in outerWall:
        if pos[1] > 90 and pos[3] < 680:

            if pos[0] <= wall[0] and pos[0] <= wall[2]:
                if pos[1] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
                    return True

            if pos[2] <= wall[0] and pos[2] <=wall[2]:
                if pos[3] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
                    return True

        if pos[3] > 680 or pos[1] < 20:
            return True

        if pos[1] > 20 and pos[1] < 90:
            if pos[0] < 20:
                return True
            if pos[2] > 780:
                return True
            if pos[2] > 385 and pos[2] < 415:
                return True
            if pos[0] > 385 and pos[0] < 415:
                return True

        if pos[1] > 90 and pos[3] < 680:

            if pos[0] >= 800 - wall[0] and pos[0] >= 800 - wall[2]:
                if pos[1] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
                    return True

            if pos[2] >= 800 - wall[0] and pos[2] >= 800 - wall[2]:
                if pos[3] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
                    return True

    for wall in list_of_walls:
        if pos[1] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
            if pos[0] in range(wall[0], wall[2]):
                return True
            if pos[2] in range(wall[0], wall[2]):
                return True
        elif pos[3] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
            if pos[0] in range(wall[0], wall[2]):
                return True
            if pos[2] in range(wall[0], wall[2]):
                return True
        if pos[1] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
            if pos[0] >= 800 - wall[2] and pos[0]<= 800 - wall[0]:
                return True
            if pos[2] >= 800 - wall[2] and pos[2]<= 800 - wall[0]:
                return True
        elif pos[3] in range(wall[1], wall[3]):
            if pos[0] >= 800 - wall[2] and pos[0]<= 800 - wall[0]:
                return True
            if pos[2] >= 800 - wall[2] and pos[2]<= 800 - wall[0]:
                return True

    return False 

def first_teleport(self):
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    if pos[1] > 290 and pos[1] < 350:
        if pos[0] < 0:
            return True
    return False

def second_teleport(self):
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    if pos[3] > 290 and pos[3] < 350:
        if pos[2] > 800:
            return True
    return False
```

class Menu():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.m = Tk()
    self.m.title("Pac-man")
    image1 = Image.open("/home/tano/The_Pac-man_game/pacman.jpg")
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
    label1 = Label(self.m, image = photo )
    label1.image = photo
    label1.pack()
    play_button = Button(self.m,text="Play", command = self.Play).pack()
    exit_button = Button(self.m,text="Exit", command = self.Exit).pack()

def Play(self):
    self.m.destroy()
    g = Game()
    g.mainloop()

def Exit(self):
    self.m.destroy()

def mainloop(self):
    while 1:
        self.m.update_idletasks()
        self.m.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

class Ghost(Pacman):

```
def __init__(self, canvas, color):
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 35, 35, fill = color)
    self.canvas.move(self.id, 350, 220)
    self.x = -2
    self.y = 0

def movement(self):
    if self.x > 0:
        self.turn_right
    if self.x < 0:
        self.turn_left
    if self.y > 0:
        self.go_down
    if self.y < 0:
        self.go_up

def change_direction(self):
    z = random.randrange(1, 4)
    if z == 1:
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 2
    elif z == 2:
        self.x = 2
        self.y = 0
    elif z == 3:
        self.x = 0
        self.y = -2
    elif z == 4:
        self.x = -2
        self.y = 0



outerWall = [ [5, 5, 5, 200], [5, 5, 400, 5], [20, 20, 20, 200],
[20, 20, 385, 20], [5, 200, 5, 215], [20, 200, 150, 200], [5, 215, 135, 215], [135, 215, 135, 275],[150, 200, 150, 290], [135, 215, 135, 275], [5, 290, 150, 290], [5, 275, 135, 275], [5, 350, 150, 350], [5, 365, 135, 365],
[150, 350, 150, 440] , [135, 365, 135, 425], [20, 440, 150, 440], [5, 425, 135, 425], [5, 425, 5, 695], [20, 440, 20, 545], [20, 575, 20, 680], [20, 545, 60, 545], [20, 575, 60, 575], [60, 545, 60, 575], [5, 695, 795, 695], [385, 20, 385, 90], [385, 90, 400, 90], [20, 680, 780, 680]]

squareWalls = [[60, 60, 150, 90], [200, 60, 340, 90], [60, 130, 150, 150], [200, 350, 240, 440], [200, 490, 340, 510]]

BaseOfGhost = [[300, 270, 300, 370], [310, 280, 310, 360], [300, 270, 350, 270], [300, 370, 400, 370], [310, 360, 400, 360], [310, 280, 350, 280],[350, 280, 350, 270] ]

WierdWalls = [[300, 140, 500, 140], [500, 140, 500, 160], [500, 160, 410, 160],[300, 140, 300, 160], [300, 160, 390, 160], [390, 160, 390, 220], [410, 160, 410, 220], [390, 220, 410 , 220], [560, 140, 560, 200], [600, 140, 600, 290], [560, 200, 480, 200], [480, 200, 480, 220], [480, 220, 560, 220], [560, 220, 560, 290], [560, 290, 600, 290], [560, 140, 600, 140], [150, 480, 150, 575], [150, 480, 60, 480], [60, 480, 60, 500], [60, 500, 130, 500], [130, 500, 130, 575], [130, 575, 150, 575], [300, 440, 390, 440 ], [300, 440, 300, 420], [300, 420, 500, 420], [390, 440, 390, 510], [390, 510, 410, 510],[300, 580, 390, 580 ], [300, 580, 300, 550], [300, 550, 500, 550], [390, 580, 390, 640], [390, 640, 410, 640], [60, 640, 340, 640], [60, 640, 60, 620], [60, 620, 200, 620], [200, 620, 200, 550], [200, 550, 220, 550,],[220, 550, 220, 620], [220, 620, 340, 620], [340, 620, 340, 640] ] 

list_of_walls = [[300,140,500,160],[390,160,410,220], [560,140,600,290],[560,200,480,220], [240,200,320,220],[240,140,200,290],[150,480,130,575], [650,480,670,575], [150,480,60,500], [650,480,740,500], [300,420,500,440], [390,440,410,510], [300,550,500,580], [390,580,410,640], [60,620,340,640], [460,620,740,640], [200,550,220,620], [580,550,600, 620], [300, 270, 400, 370]]

m = Menu()
m.mainloop()
```

My concern is if this function `hitwall()` is too big, because I'm using it twice in this main loop so far and I will need two times more ...
I'll be very happy if someone helps me find a solution to this problem because this project is pretty important to me.

Comment: One small code optimization would be to do range checking using `if low < value < high:` instead of `if value > low and value < high:`.

Comment: you need to fix the markup of your question. Some of the code isn't marked as code, making your code impossible to correctly copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls to `sleep` cause your program to lag. There may be other problems, but that's definitely one of them. You shouldn't have your own `mainloop` method, you should use the built-in `mainloop` function.

You can do this by removing the while statement from `mainloop`, removing the sleep statement and the calls to `update` and `update_idletasks`, and then having it use the `after` command to cause itself to run every few milliseconds.

It would look something like this:

```
def animate(self):

    <all of the code for updating the display>

    self.after(30, self.animate)
```

Here's the full version:

```
def animate(self):
    if self.running:
        if not self.Pac.hitwall():
            self.Pac.canvas.move(self.Pac.id, self.Pac.x, self.Pac.y)
        if self.Pac.feed():
            self.score = self.score + 10
            self.scoreid.config(text = "SCORE: {0}".format(self.score))
        if self.Pac.first_teleport():
            self.Pac.canvas.move(self.Pac.id, 760, 0)

        if self.Pac.second_teleport():
            self.Pac.canvas.move(self.Pac.id, -760, 0)

        if not self.Blinky.hitwall():
            self.Blinky.canvas.move(self.Blinky.id, self.Blinky.x, self.Blinky.y)
        if self.Blinky.hitwall():
            self.Blinky.change_direction()

        self.after(30, self.animate)
```

You can problem use `else` in a few places to cut down on the amount of computation. For example, if `hitwall()` returns `True`, there's probably no need to also call `feed()`, right? And, if the pacman hits the first teleport there's no need to check to see if it's in the second teleport. With proper use of `else` you can probably reduce computations by a third or more.

Also, you're calling self.Blinky.hitwall() twice during each iteration. Shouldn't you be calling that only once?

Comment: Your answer really helped!!! Thank you very much! I didn't know about that after method. Probably because this is my first 2D game project ... Thanks to you, hopefully, I will finish it :)

Comment: @SpmiR: I believe you'd call it In `Menu.play()` with `g.animate()` instead of the `g.mainloop()` you now have.

Answer (score 1):

At game initialization, you could do some preprocessing and logically divide the playing field up into quadrants, and then build a list for each of the them consisting only of the walls that are fully or partially in the region.

With lists like that, you could speed up `hitwall()` by only looking at walls that correspond to region(s) the `Pacman` is currently in (and ignore those in the lists for other regions). This would cut down the number of comparisons needed *significantly* — by as much as 75% if the walls are randomly distributed and the `Pacman` is completely within only one of the quadrants.